# Cant get front end form to post to wordpress

Tags: wp-insert-post, front-end

Long time lurker, first time poster, and big time PHP noob.

Apologies if my question is a little vague, but I have the code below and I know I'm doing some sort of schoolboy error but it just won't send the form contents to a post.

The basic out line is one form, you submit a URL, then another form appears with meta data in it, then that form gets submitted to a WordPress post. Its this last bit that's not working, it just pushes you back to the first form and doesn't post the data.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: page-url
*/
?>



<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); ?>

<div id="content" class="clearfix fullwidth">






<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">




<?php
/* if the "submit" variable does not exist, the form has not been submitted - display initial page */
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {


?>


    <form action="" method="post">
    Enter your url: <input name="formuserurl">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">


    </form>


<?php
    }
else {
/* if the "submit" variable exists, the form has been submitted - look for and process form data */


function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    return $data;
}


$enteredurl = $_POST['formuserurl'];
$html = file_get_contents_curl($enteredurl);


//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');


//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');


for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}


?>


<form action="" method="post">
Url: <input name="_url2" value="<?php echo $enteredurl; ?>" id="">
<br />
Title: <input name="_title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" id="">
<br />
Tags: <input name="_tags" value="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" id="">
<br />
Description: <textarea name="_description" cols="" rows="" value="" id=""><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
<br />
Category: <?php wp_dropdown_categories('tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0'  ); ?>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submitpost" value="Go">

<!--<input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="post" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
-->

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>


</form>
<?php
}
?>




<?php
/* This is to post the form content to wordpress*/

if (!isset($_POST['submitpost'])) {

    }
else {
/* This is to post the form content to worpdress*/


if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['_title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['_title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the wine name';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['_description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['_description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter some notes';
    }

    $tags = $_POST['_tags'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['_categories']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

             //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
    wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['_tags']);

    //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
    $link = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect( $link );

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

}




?>


</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>







</div> <!-- #content -->

<div id="content-bottom-bg"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Probably not causing the problem but you can't use `wp_redirect` that late and `$_POST['_categories']` should be just `$_POST['categories']`. Finally, by your logic after the second submission the original form will always display. Can't quite see why the post is not being created at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments above, but part of the problem is that you are checking that

```
$_POST['action'] == "new_post"
```

In the example you've given you have **commented out the hidden 'action' field**; which, in any case is set to `post` not `new-post`. I believe you a trying to check the nonce...

To do that (following the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce)), once you've checked the **action**, do:

```
$nonce=$_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
if (! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'new-post') ) die('Well that was naughty.');
```

Also, I don't think it's necessary to check:

```
'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Finally, before using `wp_insert_post`. You should check that the category is set (see above comments too). You should probably `intval` the posted category data before inserting as an array into the `wp_insert_post` arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, something to look into certainly. As I said im still feeling my way around PHP. I think i will need to study the intval a bit more as well. Havent managed to get it to post yet though

Comment: I ended up rejigging the code into a chain of 3 pages and changing the code that posts to wordpress, got it working. Thanks for your help!